# Use skinning and cloth simulation at the same time

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics

I created a skinned animation, but I have no idea how to make use physic simulation and skinning for the cloth at the same time. When I use skinning, physics doesn't work, when I use physics, animations make cloth drops.
Here is the link to the blender file

[Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J3f0_PYKir10jlRS5l3dY_sCCGFgHvRu)

Screenshot : 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the cloth I recommend using the cloth simulation instead of rigging it.

The problem you might have encountered when trying cloth simulation ("cloth drops") is the wrong order in which two modifiers are: For the human body the collision modifier comes before the armature modifier. This is a problem because the movement and also the location of the objects collision isn't affected by the rig.

Here is how to fix it:

[image]